# QT, VTK project on linux not running

Tags: c++, linux, qt, vtk, itk

I am trying to launch a ITK/VTQ project with Qt. The project runs on Windows 10, but not on Ubuntu.

I have the following error during launching the project:

```
X Error: BadColor (invalid Colormap parameter) 12
  Major opcode: 1 (X_CreateWindow)
  Resource id:  0x4a00001
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 7 (X_ReparentWindow)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 10 (X_UnmapWindow)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 12 (X_ConfigureWindow)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 8 (X_MapWindow)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 8 (X_MapWindow)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 2 (X_ChangeWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
X Error: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 3
  Major opcode: 3 (X_GetWindowAttributes)
  Resource id:  0x480001a
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

Here is my code :

```
void ImageViewerWidget::InitRender()
{

/*** INITIALIZATION ***/

// init the actor
m_texturedQuad = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
_openGLproperty = static_cast<vtkOpenGLProperty*>(m_texturedQuad->GetProperty());

// init the quad
_quadPolyData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();


// create the texture object
_textureCoordinates = vtkSmartPointer<vtkFloatArray>::New();
_textureCoordinates->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
_textureCoordinates->SetName("TextureCoordinates");

float tuple[3] = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
_textureCoordinates->InsertNextTuple(tuple);
tuple[0] = 1.0; tuple[1] = 0.0; tuple[2] = 0.0;
_textureCoordinates->InsertNextTuple(tuple);
tuple[0] = 1.0; tuple[1] = 1.0; tuple[2] = 0.0;
_textureCoordinates->InsertNextTuple(tuple);
tuple[0] = 0.0; tuple[1] = 1.0; tuple[2] = 0.0;
_textureCoordinates->InsertNextTuple(tuple);


// create the itk/vtk converter
m_itkToVtkConverter = itk::ImageToVTKImageFilter<itk::Image<float, 3> >::New();


/*** Init the Renderer ***/
m_imageRenderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
m_imageRenderer->SetBackground(1,1,1); // Background color white
m_imageRenderer->ResetCamera();


/*** Init the Render Window ***/
m_imageRenderWindow = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
m_imageRenderWindow->AddRenderer(m_imageRenderer);


/*** Init the Shader ***/
SetActiveShader("BasicShader");


/*** Set Render Window to viewer ***/
// FIXME: the software crashes here on GNU/Linux
viewer->SetRenderWindow(m_imageRenderWindow);

}
```

I found that the problem is here :

```
viewer->SetRenderWindow(m_imageRenderWindow);
```

How I can correct this error message ?

Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big chunk of your code (`_textureCoordinates` and stuff above) is not connected to the rest. And what you have shown here is not a runnable example, but it looks like you are not properly setting up VTK (compare with [VTK hello world](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Rendering/Cylinder)).

Have you tried looking at some of the [examples](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx) on VTK wiki? Also, why don't you start with a working [VTK/QT example](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/SideBySideRenderWindowsQt) and gradually extend it?